# How do I override/delete main/home (body) background image in different components

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 6 for my front-end web dev. I have a main background image set inside styles.css file like this.

```
body {
    background: url('http://yesofcorsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/4468_guitar.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have different components in my project, and I'm trying to override or delete my body's background image inside a particular component.
For example, if I have a "MartinList" component, I've tried to override/delete the background image by adding a body tag with a class to the martin-list-component.html and change the background image URL inside martin-list.component.css. But this only changes a small part of the background.
I kinda understand why, because my angular project is structured like this.

```
<body>
   <app-root>
      <app-nav></app-nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </app-root>
</body>
```

So what I've tried was basically adding a new body tag inside the router-outlet, which would only partially override the main body tag's background image. How can I solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: adding a new body tag ? You're a thug :)

Comment: add your background image to the app.component.css with :host{}

Comment: Can you specify a little bit? Where do I use host? I'm fairly new to front-end.

Comment: @Maihan Nijat answer is good, try to use `@HostBinding` in your app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Use `[style.background-image]="'url({{path}})'"` instead of adding background property in `style.css`.

Create a service and use `BehaviorSubject`

You can use default background instead of ''.

```
private backgroundSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
bgObservable = this.backgroundSource.asObservable();
```

Use the above service and `` in your main component:

```
this.bgService.bgObservable.subscribe(res => this.path = res);
```

And in each component register your background:

```
regBackgrond(bg) {
    this.backgroundSource.next(bg);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but where do I add [style.background-image]="'url({{path}})'" and what exactly is the main component that you are mentioning here? is it the main.ts file? or app.component.ts?